# How do I stop RStudio from Typing for Me?

Tags: rstudio

I am having constant problems where RStudio is typing for me.

For example, I press the up arrow (prior command), change a character, press enter, and RStudio had substituted a word, so the wrong command executed.

Is there an option to turn this off, globally?  (I want to do ALL the typing.)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "RStudio had substituted a word" Can you give a concrete example? I haven't experienced this.

Comment: Really.  Hard to believe...  I'll try to remember to do a screencap the next time it happens.

Comment: Sure is. I get this https://i.imgur.com/6NxpnPD.png - that is, a drop down with potential list of function names. At no point do I see it changing my code without my asking.

Comment: So you can keep typing as if the pop-up never happened, press enter in the middle of your edited command, and R-Studio isn't inserting any text on you (auto fill from past commands, or pop-up entries) ?

Comment: That's exactly right.